# how to remove &nbsp; in PDF invoice generated in Magento

Tags: magento

Hello Megento Experts,

I am a beginner in magento. I have set up a magento store. Now, when admin generated a PDF Ivoice for the orders, there are   symbols in place of space. As in screenshot below.

[image]

Please help me removing these   symbols.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In default magento generates the invoice pdf from the class **Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice**.

If you check in the file location

> app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php

You can see that.

But in your case, it seems that the file has been changed. This file may have been overridden or overwritten in your local folder. Search for the same file location in your local folder

> app\code\local

You may find the file.

If it is there, check for **&nbsp** in that file.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi, no mage/sales folder in app/code/local... so I guess it is in core only.. but in core file, I can not see any **&nbsp;** character

Comment: you can use die(); statement in the core file to check whether it is rendering from core file or not.But i guess it has been overridden by some custom module.

Comment: Also, when I change currency, $nbsp; removes... its only with Rs.

Comment: try changing the currency symbol from "system --> Magnage currency -->symbols"